# Shell command to determine if file `foo` is a truncation of file `bar`

Tags: bash, shell, diff, truncate

Say I have two files, `foo` and `bar`. If I wanted to verify they had the same contents, I could run:

```
diff -q foo bar
```

and check that the exit code was zero. Similarly, I could do the same thing for files with different contents, and look for a nonzero exit status.

Now, suppose in our case file `foo` is 500 bytes and file `bar` is several megabytes -- but the first 500 bytes of `bar` are identical to the entire file `foo`. Is there a simple command to verify this sort of condition, preferably without parsing the output of a large diff?

Would it change anything if the files were both binary instead of text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cmp` seems made for this:

```
cmp -n $(stat -c %s file1) file1 file2
```

`$(stat -c %s file1)` is the size of `file1`, `cmp -n 123 file1 file2` compares the first 123 bytes of `file1` and `file2`.

Comment: This is just about perfect. Although on OS X, getting the file size needs to be tweaked to something like `stat -f %z`. Still, seems to work great.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could use `split` to obtain the first N bytes of the file, where N is the length of the smaller file, then `diff` those:

```
split -b "$(wc -c < foo)" bar out
diff -q foo outaa
```

As [smitelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1713313/smitelli) points out in the comments, the files generated by `split` must be cleaned up afterwards. You could use something like `rm out??` to do that (the default length of the suffix is 2 characters on my system).

Comment: It should be noted that if `bar` is significantly larger than `foo`, the split will dump up to 676 `out*` files into the working directory that must be cleaned up afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect we can use `cmp` command over here. It just checks for the first mismatch and provides retrun status as below,

```
       0     Files are identical.
       1     Files are not identical.
       2     Inaccessible or missing argument.
```

In ur case it gives the message "cmp: EOF on foo" and returns 1. 
Its faster than diff

Answer (score 0):

You can `read` through the files byte-wise, something like:

```
while read -n 1 -u 7 byte; do
      read -n 1 -u 6 bite
      if [ "$byte" != "$bite" ]; then
          echo "Not a subset"
          break
      fi
 done 6<big_file 7<small_file
```

Comment: Any significance to the choice of `6` and `7` for the file descriptors?

Comment: @smitelli none what-so-ever!